# Issue with haskell install using stack

Tags: haskell-stack

I tried installing Haskell using stack as given on this page https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/install_and_upgrade/#windows

I have downloaded and installed Haskell.[image]

When I try to run stack, it just runs through and closes in less than a second. Can somebody please clarify as to what is happening?

Comment: It's a CLI program. Try running it with  `stack --help` in your shell.

Answer (score 0):

From the webpage you linked to:
"Unpack the archive and place stack.exe **somewhere on your %PATH%** (see Path section below) and you can then **run stack on the command line**."

If you double click on "stack"(.exe), it opens a command window, executes the program and closes again.

In other words, store "stack" in a directory that is in your PATH environment variable, then open cmd.exe and run stack.exe from there.
Usually if you run such a program without any parameters, some information should appear about how to proceed from there.